# Web-parts do not align on page

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, sharepoint-addin, web-part-zone

**Setup:** I have a SharePoint page where I have two lists (call it List A & List B). List A is placed in a left-hand webpart zone (any left-hand zone) and List B is placed in the right-hand webpart zone (again, any right-hand zone but matched the level/row of List A placement.

**What I expect:** both webparts show on the page with List A on the left and List B on the right and both aligned at the top of each zone and in-line

**What I get:** List A is displayed at the top of the zone OK but List B webpart is pushed below down the page and aligned below List A

**Current Workaround:** I have added a empty Content Editor webpart above each list in the relevant webpart, this seems to force List A and List B to align at the top of there zones for some reason but does leave a empty space above the lists that is undesirable.

**Question:** Is the a complete fix for sharepoint so this issue doesn't happen elsewhere (I have experienced this on different pages) or at least a fix that doesn't mean I have unwanted space above the Lists in question?Kind reagrds,

John

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug and currently I have a workaround rather than a fix!

This happens after introducing other webparts on to the page, particularly Content Editor Web Part (CEWP). Removing the webparts doesn't always fix the issue but adding CEWP in left and right columns above the WP in question will realign the two lists. At a later date I was able to remove the CEWP's. Implementing CEWP's to help realign seemed to work for me but did have to play around a bit.

John